# Simulate Enter on keyboard JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

There is an input box for entering number and dumping to the page of a PDF .

user will put the page number in input box and press" enter "on keyboard

i need to Simulate Enter on keyboard in JavaScript.

i tried the following , but it didnt jump to the page i want .

```
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("change", true, true);
    event.eventName = "change";
    document.getElementById('input').dispatchEvent(event);

var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
    event.eventName = "keydown";
      document.getElementById('input').dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: A dispatched event just fires the attached event handler, it doesn't fire the default action of the event. You could add a keydown listener to the input, and submit the form in that listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as per below:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
// Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   // Cancel the default action, if needed
   event.preventDefault();
   // Trigger the action you want for eg; below code will do the button click action    
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
   }
});
```

Hope it helps your problem.

Comment: thankyou for answering my question , but there are no button in my program .  ;(

Comment: May I know what exactly you want to do when user click the enter button in input text box?

Comment: there is only a input box for entering number then show the specific page of PDFs,   i want to Simulate the Enter on the keyboard , then i can change the page of pdf with js

Comment: So, it means that user will put the page number in input box and then will click the enter button. After that it will print the specific page number of PDFs. Am I right?

Comment: correct partially ,   it means that user will put the page number in input box and press" enter "on keyboard

Comment: I see. If so, why not you just put the button which will trigger the print function. I think it will be much easier for user to understand and more user friendly. But I don't know exactly what your program will do. I just give you the suggestion only.

Comment: yes , thankyou for ur suggestion , its a plug in library for showing PDF , so it all set up . i cant add a button for it tho ; /  btw thx for ur time